# anonymous class error when changing OnClickListener of button

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I want to change the action of button in my android application and when I write this code, an anonymous class error is appeared, and I don't know why. So could you help me please?.
the error is:

> View.OnClickListener is an anonymous class

And code is:

```
color_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   public void old_background(View v_1) {
     if (v_1.getId() == R.id.button2) {        
        RelativeLayout background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.bg);
        ImageButton newButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        Button color_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        EditText newUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.KidUname);
        background.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dora);
        newButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.flower_2);
        color_Button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_button);
        color_Button.setText("Diego !!");
        color_Button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));
        newUsername.setHint("Click the flower");
     }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write all the code that has to be executed when a button is clicked inside `onClick()`. In your code you are missing the `onClick()` and thus you are getting an error.

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

> `onClick()` is called when a view has been clicked.

```
color_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       public void onClick(View v_1) {
            if (v_1.getId() == R.id.button2) {
               RelativeLayout background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.bg);
               ImageButton newButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
               Button color_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
               EditText newUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.KidUname);
               background.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dora);
               newButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.flower_2);
               color_Button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_button);
               color_Button.setText("Diego !!");
               color_Button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));
               newUsername.setHint("Click the flower");
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, only this message appears (thanks for the feedback! Once you eam a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score), I'm really sorry :(